# onkeypress event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, onkeypress

I'm looking for a solution for a (as it seems) common problem.

I want JavaScript to check a specific format when entering data in a input-field.

This is what I've got:

HTML:

```
<input onkeypress=" return fieldFormat(event)">
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Checks spelling in realtime, if JavaScript is enabled.
    function fieldFormat(event){
        var charCode = (window.event) ? window.event.keyCode : event.keyCode;
        var parts = event.target.value.split('.');
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 &&(charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) || (parts.length > 1 && charCode == 46))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

This works fine in Chrome and IE. But for some reason, Firefox gives me troubles ^^

Any hints?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I did check before the answer from Iaruiss. No, there weren't any errors. I think i begin to understand the problem.
I'm a bloody noob ^^ That's why I wasn't able to figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers use `keyCode`, others use `which`, so try this:

```
function fieldFormat(event){
    var e = event || window.event,
        charCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
        parts = e.target.value.split('.');
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 &&(charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) || (parts.length > 1 && charCode == 46))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: YOU, SIR, JUST MADE MY DAY!

Comment: Just to be clear: Your answer works perfect for me =) Thank's again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one - seems like it's common https://support.mozilla.org/pl/questions/998291

Comment: Thank you for your hint.
The answer from Iaruiss works like a charm. But it's always better to understand the whole thing ;)